# Cache geocodes when user enters the same address multiple times

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geocoding

Does Google Maps V3 API have any form of built in caching system for geocoding? I was thinking whether the usage limit for a user will be reached if that user enters an address say "Boston, MA" and continues clicking a button that geocodes that same address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any, but it would be easy to put your own cache in front of the geocoding. Also you can try using client-side geocoding, which should eliminate the problem for the most part.

Check out this link:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geocodestrat.html

If you decide to do your geocoding cache, make sure you aren't violating the terms of service.  A while back you couldn't store the geocode results... I'm not sure if that's still true or not.

Comment: I just checked and caching is ok, if your only using the cache for google maps: You may use the HTTP geocoder to geocode addresses outside of your Google Maps API application so that they may be cached and later displayed using one of the Google Maps APIs, but locations obtained using the Geocoding Web Service may not be used by any other application, distributed by other means, or resold.